# What is the best way to listen to the graphQL subscription using tokio-tungstenite and make http requests like query and mutation using graphql_client

Tags: rust, async-await, graphql, rust-tokio

I am trying to run websocket subscription and http query/mutation on graphql endpoint in parallel.

So far I was able to connect to the subscription endpoint using tokio-tungstenite crate

as below

```
pub async fn SubscribeToChannel() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {

    let (stdin_tx, stdin_rx) = futures_channel::mpsc::unbounded();
    tokio::spawn(read_stdin(stdin_tx));
    let url = url::Url::parse("wss://************.appsync-realtime-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/graphql?payload=e30=&header=*********
").unwrap();

    let mut request = url.into_client_request()?;
    let headers = request.headers_mut();
    headers.insert("Sec-WebSocket-Protocol", "graphql-ws".parse().unwrap());
    let (ws_stream, _) = connect_async(request).await.expect("Failed to connect");
    println!("WebSocket handshake has been successfully completed");
```

I can also make seperate https calls like query/mutation using graphql_client crate in the same project.

How can I make everything run on 1 thread as  tokio-tungstenite websocket runs on tokio block_on and graphql_client https calls like query/mutation never get chance to run.

I want to make mutate request after every 1 minute

here is the mutation query which works if websocket is not running and blocking the thread

```
async fn perform_mutation_query(variables: create_blog::Variables,
) -> Result<Response<create_blog::ResponseData>, Error> {
    let request_body = createBlog::build_query(variables);
    let client = reqwest::Client::new();

    let res = client.post("https://*************.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/graphql")
        .header("x-api-key", "*******************")
        .json(&request_body)
        .send()
        .await?;
    let response_body: Response<create_blog::ResponseData> = res.json().await?;
    Ok(response_body)
}
```

I tried to use tokio::join which works the first time but once http call is complete, I am not able to call the mutation again

```
async fn run() {
  tokio::join!(
      callSubscription(),      //SubscribeToChannel
      callMutation(),          //perform_mutation_query
  );
}
```

Comment: You can use tokio::spawn to spawn both tasks and then use tokio::join! to wait for both tasks to complete.

Comment: I want to keep the websocket running and make mutation http call every 1 minutes. So join will never resolve as websocket will keep on running. On other hand mutation http query will complete every time

Comment: In that case, you can use `tokio::time::interval` to create a timer that triggers every minute. You can then run the WebSocket subscription and the mutation HTTP call concurrently without blocking each other.

Comment: Thank you.  

So you are saying run the following seperately 


`async fn runSubscription() {
  tokio::join!(
      callSubscription(),      //SubscribeToChannel
      
  );
}`


`async fn runMutation() {
  tokio::join!(
      callMutation(),          //perform_mutation_query
  );
}`
And keep on calling `runMutation()`.   ` using tokio::time::interval` ?